# "Ubuntu One discontinuing" annoying message

Tags: ubuntu-one

Good day, people
It's been 8 days since the announced discontinuation of Ubuntu One, which I've never used at all, but I'm still receiving the notice for "June 1st discontinuation" every time I boot up my 12.04.
Will that message ever go away? 
Thanks.

Comment: Seems to me you have U1 installed (but never used it)... so why not delete the ubuntu one package from USC?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem, and I have already removed Ubuntu One, via Software Center. Even though the package is gone, and today's date is June 10, I still received a notification telling me the service would be shutting down June 1.

Comment: Yes, Rinzwind, I forgot to mention I uninstalled it long ago.

Comment: I also uninstalled Ubuntu One, and receive that annoying message.

Comment: If you get the notification, you did not uninstall all of ubuntu one. You probably only removed the control panel, not the actual sync client.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to remove the `python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol` package, you can do this via the Software Center by clicking the following button and then removing it:

[image: sftctr]

Or via the command line:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol
```

Comment: This approach sure removes more packages: gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0* libkms1* libsyncdaemon-1.0-1* libubuntuoneui-3.0-1*
  odbcinst* odbcinst1debian2* python-ubuntuone-client*
  python-ubuntuone-control-panel* python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol*
  ubuntuone-client* ubuntuone-client-gnome* ubuntuone-control-panel*
  ubuntuone-control-panel-qt* ubuntuone-couch* unixodbc*

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following packages via synaptic as I had not found the answer above. This also worked

[image: removal log]

Comment: Why the downvote? Did you bother to test?