# ubuntu one shutting down message

Tags: ubuntu-one

Every time I boot my computer, I get the auto pop-up in the upper right notifying me that Ubuntu One is closing June 1, 2014.  I can't figure out how to get it to stop showing that message.  I have disconnected all of my devices from Ubuntu One, and clearly June 1 has already past, and I still get the pop-up.  Any advice?

Comment: try remove ubuntu one

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the Ubuntu One client, I could not find any other way, not that the Ubuntu One client is of any use anymore.

Comment: Removal did not seem to work for others having the same issue http://askubuntu.com/q/480928/89515